# How to change JavaScript variable from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a global JavaScript variable `btnEnabled` that starts as `true`. It will define the state of the submit button of my form. When filling a `div` using innerHTML in an AJAX call, this variable should become `false` (because some `select` are yet empty), and the related button, disabled. That's the essential part of the PHP code:

```
echo " <select id='sel$line1' onchange='selAddChange()'>"; // there are many selects like this
// ...
echo "<option value='none' selected></option>"; // if this is selected, it's because some value have not been found on database, so the next line should be executed on the client browser
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>btnEnabled = false;</script>"; // should disable JavaScript variable related to 'Add' button
// ...
echo "</select><br>";
```

However, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769624/1086511) that innerHTML doesn't execute the JavaScript automatically. But it also adverts to avoid using `eval`.

If I start the variable as `false`, then I may have no `select` at all, and need to change the variable's value the same way.

I've seen the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189198/set-javascript-variable-from-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304105/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-from-php-back-to-javascript) as well, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

So, how can I change the JavaScript variable value from PHP/Server side?

Comment: Call something with AJAX from Server, and put the result in the variable. You can do this within the onload method of body.

Comment: @Am.rez I'm already doing an AJAX request from the client, and putting the result in a div. Do you mean making another AJAX from the Server? I've never seen such thing. Are you sure?

Comment: What's up with the down voters? The accepted answer wasn't found in any of the 3 questions linked. The accepted answer works. The text is clear enough, so as to receive a useful answer. So what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return XML or JSON from server containing two fields: the HTML code and the new value for variable; and then on JS side extract these two values from response and put in their places.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a good solution. Not sure why 2 down votes uncommented, though.